# Ortho-rectifying standard non-rectified Maxar satellite imagery

Tags: raster, dem, orthorectification, maxar-digitalglobe

For a project we received 50cm brushed up LV2A OR2A BGRN-spectre satellite imagery from Maxar. No GCP are mentioned in the metadata and at the intersection of overlapping map tiles the angle of the image is clearly different and thus cannot be easily merged. We received .imd, . rpb, .til, .txt, and .xml files with it and I have been desperately trying to ortho-rectify the images so we can analyze and use them but am failing to find any instructions on how to approach this. Could anyone please tell me how to make the images readable in QGIS? **Can I still ortho-rectify it and make it better readable without GCP to get rid off the shift between two tiles?**

Image as received:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely use your existing imagery to georeference the image to your existing imagery to help align the two data.  See here for help on [georeferencing in QGIS](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/training_manual/forestry/map_georeferencing.html).  There are also numerous tutorials available for georeferencing in QGIS on the internet.

[Orthorectify](https://www.l3harrisgeospatial.com/Learn/Blogs/Blog-Details/ArtMID/10198/ArticleID/16225/Georeference-Image-Registration--Orthorectification)?  No, not unless you have ground control and a suitable surface model. I see that there is a [plugin for orthorectification in QGIS](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/tags/orthorectification/) but I have not tried that plugin.  If you want to proceed with orthorectification you might want to have a look at [Orfeo](https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/CookBook/Applications/app_OrthoRectification.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion @GBG! I have followed the georeferencing in QGIS instructions yet somehow my georeferenced image shows up miles away from where it should be. Project CRS and Target CRS are both EPSG:32628 - WGS 84 / UTM zone 28N, transformation type is linear, and with the GCPs in the georeferencer tool I do see a distance that appears to match the difference between the two tiles. Where did it go wrong?